# Group by clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am struggling in grouping my data, currently i have this

[image]

if i group this result via name(Column 1) my data will become

[image]

what i what is this

[image]

as you can see, i wnat to group my column 1 where name(column2) is same any idea how to achive that.

**PS:** i query that result on my 6 tables here is my query

```
select a.name, b.name, d.price, e.id from tbl1 a, tbl2 b, tbl3 c,
tbl4 d, tbl5 e, tbl6 f
where a.id=c.patron_id and b.id=c.cinema_id and d.movies_schedule_list_id=e.id 
and e.movies_schedule_id=f.id and f.cinema_id=b.id and f.movie_date = '2014/10/31'
order by b.name;
```

i tried to put

```
group by a.name having b.name= ??
```

But i don't know where can i equal the b.name.Help me please, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just combine two fields as your group by criterion like so

```
group by a.name, b.name
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your where clause, put in
GROUP BY a.name, b.name
ORDER BY b.name;